# no video in Ubuntu 16.10 boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, 16.10, hibernate, toshiba-satellite

16.04 boots into 1 of 3 modes:

1. normal
2. no video (with response after some timeout, most frequent)
3. no video, no response

Ubuntu 16.10 boots only in variant (3).
I'm running on a Toshiba Satellite P740D.

How can I correct the video response for booting in Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: OSes do not boot "hibernated" or "suspended". Aren't you confusing a "no video" situation with the aforementioned states? Please edit and provide more informations: Is it a dual boot? How was Ubuntu installed, UEFI or Legacy? If the latter, why do you think you had to do that? Have you installed Nvidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: Video will either drop out or not during the Ubuntu splash/countdown screen. In 16.04, after some time > 10min, system will respond with video, sometimes; not in 16.10. Stock video drivers as far as I know. Install from web .iso.  Had 16.04 running and system updater updated to 16.10 and no response. Had to go back to a previous version to then pull down 16.04. Single boot install.

Comment: It's a "no video" issue indeed. Because your Toshiba has a Nvidia GT525M which requires proprietary drivers.  Versions from 361 to 378 should work.